# How can I mock a method an external script uses?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This is specific to Jenkins but hoping there is a generic groovy feature that can help me here.

I have a groovy script (`myCustomStep.grooy`) I want to unit test. It MUST be written like it is below (it cannot be a class). It will include methods that are available during Jenkins run time but not locally and I want to mock them out.

Here is one of these scripts and a corresponding test. How do I mock out `echo` without modifying `myCustomStep.groovy`?

```
# vars/myCustomStep.grooy
def call(Map config) {
  def paramOne = config.paramOne
  echo paramOne
}
 
class MyCustomStepTest {
  // I tried to define it here but I get "No signature of method: myCustomStep.echo()"
  def echo(message) {
    println "$message"
  }

  @Test
  public void "sdfsdfsdf"() throws Exception {
    def aaa = new GroovyShell().parse( new File( 'vars/myCustomStep.groovy' ) )
    aaa deployment: "sdlfsdfdsf"
  }
}
```

I can't have myCustomStep.grooy accept `echo` as an argument. Is there a way to monkey patch `echo` into the `myCustomStep` namespace?

EDIT: I found a simple solution but now I want to know how I can attach methods to myCustomStep for all tests instead of having to redefine for every test. I tried to do this in a `@Before` method (using junit) but the myCustomStep obj wasn't available to the tests.

```
class MyCustomStepTest {
    def myCustomStep = new GroovyShell().parse( new File( 'vars/myCustomStep.groovy' ) )

  @Test
  public void "sdfsdfsdf"() throws Exception {
    // how can I attach this once for use by all my tests?
    myCustomStep.echo = { String message -> println "$message" }
    myCustomStep deployment: "sdlfsdfdsf"
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I was just confused about where to instantiate the object. Looks like I just need to create the object outside of the @before method and then update it inside of it.

```
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    myCustomStep.echo = { String message -> println "$message" }
  }

  def myCustomStep = new GroovyShell().parse( new File( 'vars/myCustomStep.groovy' ) )
```

Comment: I attempted to delete my answer since the content of my answer has since been put in the question.  Stackoverflow won't let me delete an accepted answer.  My answer doesn't add anything to what is in the question now.

Comment: It adds the use of `Binding()` which I was unaware of and am now using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put `echo` in the binding using something like this:

```
    Binding b = new Binding()
    b.echo = { println "Hello There" }
    def shell = new GroovyShell(b)
    def aaa = shell.parse( new File( 'ars/myCustomStep.groovy' ) )
    aaa deployment: "sdlfsdfdsf"
```

Comment: I literally just made an edit asking about how to do this very thing  but in a fixture somehow. maybe its outside the scope of this question now? I'd like to create an instance of the object once and attach all the methods to it and use it in all the tests