# How can I mock this closure with parameters that wraps other methods in a groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I just asked about how to mock jenkins step/global vars for testing a custom step and got help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852237/how-can-i-mock-a-method-an-external-script-uses?noredirect=1#comment121683050_68852237)

This is how I'm doing that now:

```
// vars/myCustomStep.groovy
def call(Map config) {
  def paramOne = config.paramOne

  container('my-container') {
    echo paramOne
    sh 'printenv'
  }

}

// test/vars/myCustomStep.groovy
class myCustomStepTest {

  Binding binding
  def shell
  def myCustomStep

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // Instantiate shell object and attach methods for mocking jenkins steps
    binding = new Binding()
    binding.echo = { String message -> println "$message" }
    binding.sh = { String command -> println "sh step: $message" }

    // How do I mock this??? this returns "No signature of method: myCustomStep.container() is applicable for argument types..."
    binding.container = { Closure closure -> closure }

    shell = new GroovyShell(binding)

    // Instantiate groovy script
    myCustomStep = shell.parse( new File( 'vars/myCustomStep.groovy' ) )
  }

  @Test
  public void "sdfsdfsdf"() throws Exception {
    myCustomStep paramOne: "sdlfsdfdsf"
  }
}
```

My current challenge is figuring out how to mock things like `script{}` and `container{}` closures. I can't modify the structure of myCustomStep.groovy because this is jenkins specific. The behavior I want is for the test to essentially just ignore the `container('xxx'){}` method and only execute what is inside it.

Comment: You can do the same sort of thing that was suggested in the other question.  For example, `yourBinding.container = { String s, Closure c -> println "Your mock container method was called" }`.

Comment: You said "The behavior I want is for the test to essentially just ignore the container('xxx'){} method and only execute what is inside it.".  I don't know what you mean by "inside it" but if you mean execute the closure, you could invoke `c()` inside of the closure I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: can you add that as an answer? I didn't know how to execute the closure nor what the definition was `String s, Closure c`